# python sockets,sock.connect error

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime

#User input
ServerIP = raw_input("Enter server IP: ")
RemoteServerIP = socket.gethostbyaddr(ServerIP)

print "-" * 60
print "Please wait, scanning remote host", RemoteServerIP
print "-" * 60

#Starting to scan
StartTime = datetime.now()

for port in range(1,1025):#ports 1-1024
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((RemoteServerIP, port))
    if result == 0:
        print "Port {}: \t Open".format(port)
sock.close()

#caculate the time and print to screen
EndTime = datetime.now()
TotalTime =  StartTime - EndTime 
print 'Scanning Completed in: ', TotalTime
```

Error :

```
    result = sock.connect_ex((RemoteServerIP, port))

File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth

    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

Answer (score 1):

`socket.gethostbyaddr()` [returns a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr). Accessing the first item in the *ipaddrlist* should get you what you need:

```
RemoteServerIP = socket.gethostbyaddr(ServerIP)[2][0]
```

Comment: ty very much for helping me

Comment: My pleasure! Best of luck to you.